# I have a really dumb algebra question for you

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $k_1, k_2, k_3 > 0$.  Suppose $x \leq -k_3$ and $y \leq k_2$.  What, if anything, can you say about $\frac{x}{y}$?

What if $y \geq k_2$?

Also, what can you say about $\frac{y}{x}$?

Thanks

Comment: There are no dumb questions!

Comment: I would dispute that claim, andy, but this is not a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, in terms of sign you cannot say anything since y can be both negative and positive. However, in the second case since $y\gt k_2\gt0$ you can say that $x\over y$ is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way is this... I babystepped it so to prevent problems.  I dont like playing with inequalities any more than you do.

If $y\le k_2$ then $\frac{1}{y}\ge\frac{1}{k_2}$

Let $x=-m$, then $m\ge k_3$

Multiply
$ m \frac{1}{y} \ge k_3\frac{1}{k_2} $

$ \frac{m}{y} \ge \frac{k_3}{k_2} $

Now, resubstitute

$ \frac{x}{y} \le -\frac{k_3}{k_2} $

Comment: You've (implicitly) assumed $y > 0$, though the question doesn't state that.

Comment: Fine by me; the original question (which I stated incorrectly) actually said $k_1 \leq y \leq k_2$.  Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Indeed I did. But you can use the same logic with the opposite assumption to determine more information.  Perhaps you may even conclude that you know nothing at all.